# Creating a mutiple syncLock variable for an instance

Tags: c#, object, locking, synchronized

I have two internal properties that use lazy-loading of backing fields, and are used in a multi-threaded application, so I have implemented a double-checking lock scheme as per [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Now, firstly assuming that this is an appropriate pattern, all the examples show creating a single lock object for an instance.  If my two properties are independent of each other, would it not be more efficient to create a lock instance for each property?

It occurs to me that maybe there is only one in order to avoid deadlocks or race-conditions.  A obvious situation doesn't come to mind, but I'm sure someone can show me one... (I'm not very experienced with multi-threaded code, obviously)

```
private List<SomeObject1> _someProperty1;
private List<SomeObject2> _someProperty2;
private readonly _syncLockSomeProperty1 = new Object();
private readonly _syncLockSomeProperty2 = new Object();

internal List<SomeObject1> SomeProperty1
{
  get
  {
    if (_someProperty1== null)
    {
      lock (_syncLockSomeProperty1)
      {
        if (_someProperty1 == null)
        {
          _someProperty1 = new List<SomeObject1>();
        }
      }
    }
    return _someProperty1;
  }

  set
  {
    _someProperty1 = value;
  }
}

internal List<SomeObject2> SomeProperty2
{
  get
  {
    if (_someProperty2 == null)
    {
      lock (_syncLockSomeProperty2)
      {
        if (_someProperty2 == null)
        {
          _someProperty2 = new List<SomeObject2>();
        }
      }
    }
    return _someProperty2;
  }

  set
  {
    _someProperty2 = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: The property setters are a bad code smell.  In more than one way here.

Comment: In the end I looked at the code I inherited and refactored it to make it thread-safe without the need for any locking.  So, the best solution in the end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **if** they are independent of each other, this would indeed be more efficient, as access to one wont' block access to the other. You're also on the money about the risk of a deadlock if that independence turned out to be false.

The question is, presuming that `_someProperty1 = new List<SomeObject1>();` isn't the real code for assigning to `_someProperty1` (hardly worth the lazy-load, is it?), then the question is: Can the code that fills SomeProperty1 ever call that which fills SomeProperty2, or vice-versa, through any code-path, no matter how bizarre?

Even if one can call the other, there can't be a deadlock, but if they both can call each other (or 1 call 2, 2 call 3 and 3 call 1, and so on), then a deadlock can definitely happen.

As a rule, I'd start with broad locks (one lock for all locked tasks) and then make the locks narrower as an optimisation as needed. In cases where you have, say, 20 methods which need locking, then judging the safety can be harder (also, you begin to fill memory just with lock objects).

Note that there are two issues with your code also:

First, you don't lock in your setter. Possibly this is fine (you just want your lock to prevent multiple heavy calls to the loading method, and don't actually care if there are over-writes between the `set`, and the `get`), possibly this is a disaster.

Second, depending on the CPU running it, double-check as you write it can have issues with read/write reordering, so you should either have a volatile field, or call a memory barrier. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/05/12/130935.aspx

Edit:

It's also worth considering whether it's really needed at all.

Consider that the operation itself should be thread-safe:

1. Do a bunch of stuff is done.
2. Have an object created based on that bunch of stuff.
3. Assign that object to the local variable.

1 and 2 will only happen on one thread, and 3 is atomic. Therefore, the advantage of locking is:

1. If performing step 1 and/or 2 above have their own threading issues, and aren't protected from them by their own locks, then locking is 100% necessary.
2. If it would be disastrous for something to have acted upon a value obtained in step 1 and 2, and then later to do so with step 1 and 2 being repeated, locking is 100% necessary.
3. Locking will prevent the waste of 1 and 2 being done multiple times.

So, if we can rule out case 1 and 2 as an issue (takes a bit of analysis, but it's often possible), then we've only preventing the waste in case 3 to worry about. Now, maybe this is a big worry. However, if it would rarely come up, and also not be that much of a waste when it did, then the gains of not locking would outweigh the gains of locking.

If in doubt, locking is probably the safer approach, but its possible that just living with the occasional wasted operation is better.

Answer (score 3):

If your properties are truly independent, then there's no harm in using independent locks for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

In case the two properties (or their initializers more specifically) are independent of each other, as in the sample code you provided, it makes sense to have two different lock objects. However, when the initialization occurs rarely, the effect will be negligible.

Note that you should protect the setter's code as well. The `lock` statement imposes a so called memory barrier, which is indispensable especially on multi-CPU and/or multi-core systems to prevent race conditions.

Comment: Simple setters don't require a lock; reference assignments are atomic. Only assignments that are larger than the native word size (large value types, for example) are non-atomic assignments.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: No. Atomicity has nothing to do with concurrent access and memory barriers. Read this: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

Comment: @Ondrej: Simply assigning a reference in the setter does not require a memory barrier; there is no potential for a race condition, as the only thing taking place is a single atomic operation.

Comment: @Adam: It is not just a matter of race conditions but code optimizations as well.

Comment: @Ondrej: And, as I said, the only operation taking place is a single reference assignment. There's no reordering (or any other optimizations) that can be done here.

Comment: @Adam: think in the possible content, not limited by the only one single line of code shown here.

Comment: @Ondrej: The OP asked a specific question. The answers he receives (especially in the realm of multithread-aware code) depend entirely on the code being posted being accurate. If his setter is not as it stands above, then of course there could be considerations re: caching, reordering, etc., but we can't be expected to provide meaningful, relevant answers without fully representative code.

Comment: @Adam: Giving up. Apparently you do not want to think about the consequences. The OP also stated he wasn't experienced so answers giving *more* information that was just asked for are IMHO very relevant.

Comment: @Omdrej: I simply said it wasn't necessary, not that it was a bad idea. You responded by telling me to go read an article on concurrency. As the code stands, neither memory barriers nor other concurrency controls are required; if the code is different, then they could be. That's not to say that it will necessarily *hurt* anything, but there's no need to tell him to do things that aren't required by the code.

Comment: A lock on the setter may or may not be required depending on things we simply can't know about from the code above. The getters almost certainly do need a memory barrier though, they have the classic broken-in-.NET-double-check issue (I can think of cases where one might choose just to live with that, but then one would probably choose just to live with the potential for wasteful multiple calls to the method that builds the object in the getter too.